# If this or that with Strings

Tags: java

How would one make an if statement that would take user input and then take that word I asked them to use and choose between either the uppercase or lowercase version and still run the same line of code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//text game practice

public class textGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int goblin;
    int troll;
    int spider;

    System.out.println("Would you like to play as the Mage, Warrior, or Rouge?");
    String line1 = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Okay " + line1 + " what is your name?");
    String name = scan.next();

    if (name.equals("Mage" || "mage")) {
        System.out.println("You are a mage named " + name + " from a small wizardry school in the north.");
    }
    if (name == "Warrior" || "warrior") {
        System.out.println("You are a warrior named " + name + " fresh out of the new cadets at the Gambleton Outpost.");
    }
    if (name == "Rouge" || "rouge") {
        System.out.println("You are a rouge named " + name + " you were trained by petty theives in the streets of Limburg.");
    }    
    else {
        System.out.println("You did not answer the question correctly please try again.");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `name.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. It is `if (name.equals("foo") || name.equals("bar"))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("mage")) {
    System.out.println("You are a mage named " + name + " from a small wizardry school in the north.");
}
```

In your case, it won't compile.
Instead of the `name.equals("Mage" || "mage")` use that:

```
if (name.equals("mage") || name.equals("Mage")) {
    System.out.println("You are a mage named " + name + " from a small wizardry school in the north.");
}
```

You can't use the `||` inside of the `equals` method but you can split your if clause in 2 different statements.

Comment: You're missing the big errors he's having with `||` use

Comment: Yep, I've edited my post to clarify why that won't work. Thx @HovercraftFullOfEels